# How does the GCC optimization flag reduce the CPU usage?

Tags: c, embedded

I'm doing a GUI project using LVGL,and open the monitor of LVGL to see how much CPU is used.

But the CPU usage is always 99% which makes the GUI response slowly,even there are only one button and two labels.A drawing function of the main screen takes up to 700ms to fill the array and display in the LCD.

The CPU usage reduces to 50% when I set the GCC optimization flag from none to -O3.And the drawing function takes 100ms to execute.How does it optimize this?

Comment: Compare the generated assembly code?

Comment: it reduces to 50% because your code is called periodically, and since it ends earlier, the CPU has some idle time.

Comment: You can read what kind of optimization GCC does and how to enable/disable them here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: To give a specific answer to your question, the code would be necessary. But i guess it is a bit long? Maybe you could benchmark which function needs the most time and see how GCC optimize this specific function or reduce the number of calls to that function.

Comment: In order _not_ to utilize maximum CPU, you have to design the application to use system/OS specific sleep/wait functions. None of which is the compiler's business to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to change program execution order, optimize out variables and code if it will benefit the optimizations set by the programmer.

Here you have a very simple example:

```
char *cpy(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *svd = s1;
    while((*s1++ = *s2++));
    return svd;
}
```

Not optimized code:

```
cpy:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rsi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        nop
.L2:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        lea     rax, [rdx+1]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        lea     rcx, [rax+1]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rcx
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rdx]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax], dl
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        test    al, al
        jne     .L2
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

And the optimized code:

```
cpy:
        mov     rax, rdi
        xor     edx, edx
.L2:
        movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rsi+rdx]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax+rdx], cl
        add     rdx, 1
        test    cl, cl
        jne     .L2
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6h5j8rbav